# ECDSA генерирует разную подпись

Tags: c#, криптография

Использую алгоритм ECDSA и библиотеку Bouncy Castle. Ключи беру из .pem файла, кривая, соответственно, тоже записана в файле.

При каждом выполнении алгоритма генерируется новая подпись. Почему так? Ведь должна же быть одинаковая, где ошибка?

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("MYKEY.pem");

AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(sr).ReadObject();

ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA1withECDSA");
signer.Init(true, keyPair.Private);
signer.BlockUpdate(message, 0, message.Length);
byte[] signature = signer.GenerateSignature();
```

Если сгенерить подпись открытым ключом и сравнить их, они одинаковые.

```
signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA1withECDSA");
signer.Init(false, keyPair.Public);
signer.BlockUpdate(message, 0, message.Length);
bool ok = signer.VerifySignature(signature);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это так и должно быть. В алгоритме DSA первым же шагом идет генерация случайного числа, и ECDSA наследует эту особенность. Более того, это генерируемое число должно быть случайным обязательно, повторение этого числа для двух разных сообщений раскроет приватный ключ.

Comment: А как же тогда проходит проверка подписи публичным и приватным ключами на разных машинах?

Comment: @Николай а приватным ключом подпись не проверяют, только публичным

Comment: я это и имел в виду. Сгенерили случайное число и получили подпись приватным ключом, как же тогда имея только публичный ключ можно проверить сообщение?

Comment: @Николай вы же сами написали: `signer.VerifySignature(signature)`...